# Getting apostrophs right in listings

Tags: listings

I have a very simple problem. I want to display a simple php code in Latex using listings. For example

```
{goToPage('nextpage');
}
```

My problem is, that if I compile the code the apostrophs ' are displayed as ´ in the document. I can't figure out how to change this.

Here is the Latex Code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\lstset{ %
    language=php,                     % the language of the code
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line
    % will be numbered
    inputencoding = utf8,
    numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
    showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
    showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
    showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
    extendedchars=true, 
    rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
    tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
    breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    title=\lstname,                 % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
    % also try caption instead of title
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},      % keyword style
    commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},   % comment style
    stringstyle=\color{Purple},      % string literal style
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},         % if you want to add a comment within your code
    morekeywords={*,...}            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
} 
lines=true}
\lstset{framextopmargin=50pt,frame=bottomline}
\author{Philipp Hubert}
\title{SoSci Hilfe}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=php]
    {goToPage('***');
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and things like that so that your example is a complete document. Then someone will surely answer with a change that works for the kind of document you have.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in verbatim environment

```
\begin{verbatim} Your code \end{verbatim}
```

But you should post a minimum working example to get a proper answer.

Comment: Using verbatim causes the same problem. ' is displayed as ´